# Is there a way in rails to make a model optionally belong to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I am building a rails exercise app that has both exercises and routines. I want each routine to be composed of several exercises (has_many :exercises), but an exercise doesn't necessarily have to belong to a routine. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) is always a good start. This works from Rails 5 onwards.

```
belongs_to :routine, optional: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a many-to-many relationship here, rather than a one-to-many relationship.

It would seem you would want for an Exercise to be associated with any number of Routines, and for a Routine to be associated with one or more Exercises.

You end up with something like this:

```
# app/models/routine.rb
class Routine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :exercises
end

# app/models/exercise.rb
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :routines
end

# db/migrate/1213123123123_create_exercises_routines_join_table.rb
class CreateExercisesRoutinesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.change
    create_table :exercises_routines, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :exercise_id
      t.integer :routine_id
      t.index [:category_id, :routine_id]
    end
  end
end
```